# stack exchange api post method

Tags: android, http-post, stackexchange-api

I am trying to `upvote` a question using the `stackexchange` API in android. using the URL
[https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/{questionID}/upvote](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/%7BquestionID%7D/upvote)

but in the log its just showing something like this
org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@33b2c539

API link for upvote a question is
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/upvote-question

When I am trying from API link its working, but not with the code.

Find below the code below:

String url=  "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+questionId+"/upvote";

```
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toString()); 

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", key));
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", accessToken));

                try {
                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // making request

                try {
                       response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                        Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: now please , correct that log.d and show us the log

Comment: Log.d() is not accepting response directly. it needs a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solutions.
We should pass 5 parameters to `upvote` a question.

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", key));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", accessToken));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filter", "default"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("site", "stackoverflow"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("preview", "false"));
```

Also, the http response is in JSON format (expected), but it is in Gzip type.
We need to decode the response by sending the data to GZIPInputStream and decode in in UTF-8 to read it. (mentioned nowhere in api docs)

```
            GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(entity.getContent());
            InputStreamReader ss = new InputStreamReader(gin, "UTF-8");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ss);
            String line = "", data="";
            while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                data+=line;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@33b2c539 is because of this line

```
       Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
```

try this instead

```
       String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
       Log.d("Http Post Response:", result);
```

Comment: still same with String.valueOf(response)

Comment: we have to show response in the LogCat ... try my last update

Comment: If I am trying with the same URL as above its giving some junk ��������������VJ-*�/��LQ�210ЁrsS���S����3KR2��RK3�RS�`J�sA�I�)��E@NIj�R-��g��PP������

Comment: If I use some bad request its giving HTML response with HTTP error 400

Comment: i think the encoding is the problem

Comment: I tried both but its same. httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair,"UTF-8"));
      httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

Comment: I still doubt if I am using the proper url.    String url= "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+questionId+"/upvote";         Please refer the link https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/upvote-question

Comment: you're using it as they told

Comment: Not sure why this response is not as expected.                similar question                 http://stackapps.com/questions/4461/why-am-i-getting-a-404-when-trying-to-post-a-comment

Comment: but where do you mention which site ?

Comment: i mean if it is stackoverflow or other ?

Comment: Now I tried with the below, but still same                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(5);

           nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key", key));
           nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", accessToken));
           nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("preview", "false"));
           nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("filter", "default"));
           nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("site", "stackoverflow"));

Comment: you have to add the site as parameter isn't it .. something like &site=meta or &site=stackoverflow , from this link https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/upvote-question#id=29870198&key=hhhhhhhhhh&preview=true&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true you can see that the website selected is stackoverfow and it can be changed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76256/discussion-between-charef-eddine-mechalikh-and-sudheer).