# Consuming stack exchange API

Tags: java, php, android, json, stackexchange-api

I have tried to upvote a stackoverflow question with the stack exchange api and failed. I have tried a lot but I didn't get it to work.

**URL :**

http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/35007869/upvote

**Docs**

https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/upvote-question

**Json Data :**

```
{
  "key" : "my key",
  "access_token" : "my token",
  "site" : "stackoverflow.com",
  "preview" : "false",
  "filter": "default"
}
```

I tried through fiddler with following parameters.

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: api.stackexchange.com
Content-Length: 159
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

And `POST` method. But I am failed with following error message.

```
error_id=400
error_message=site is required
error_name=bad_parameter
```

But I have provided the site in my JSON object. So Any help will be highly appreciable.

**Update**

While try this in fiddler I got following message.

[image]

Comment: Any codes for your try ? check this out too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29945301/4409113

Comment: Have you succeed in any other request?

Comment: @Alexandr no. not yet get the answer.

Comment: Did you read this? https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/write

Comment: @Empty2k12 Yes, I have read it and I have created the App also.

Answer (score 4):

You need to send them as form data, with Javascript it would be like this:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/35007869/upvote', true);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('key', 'my key');
formData.append('access_token', 'my token');
formData.append('site', 'stackoverflow.com');
formData.append('preview', 'false');
formData.append('filter', 'default');

request.send(formData);
```

Here's a guide to do it with Android: http://www.onlymobilepro.com/2013/03/16/submitting-android-form-data-via-post-method/

Comment: Can you post some example which should work in fiddler. Because I want to confirm that the API works perfectly, before start the code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the parameters as URL arguments, not as a raw JSON on the request body.
In order to perform an upvote, send the following POST request:

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/35007869/upvote?site=stackoverflow.com&key=YOUR_KEY&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN&preview=false&filter=default
```

Comment: I am getting following error while try this `POST methods expects all parameters to be submitted as a form, not on the query string`

Comment: It says not on the query string, Again you are passing all parameters on query string.

Answer (score 0):

*Your Json Data Should be send like this,it is not allowing next line*

```
{"key":"mykey","access_token":"mytoken","site":"stackoverflow.com","preview":"false","filter":"default"}
```